# Why must a biholomorphic automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ have a pole at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the proof of the first proposition in [this document](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jxr57/501-03/lecture21.pdf), why must a biholomorphic function $f \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ have a pole at infinity? I can't retrace the topological argument given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is meant by the first paragraph (it is a bit vague in my opinion), but its purpose is to indicate that $f$ has either a pole or an essential singularity at $\infty$.

I have addressed the question below without reference to the linked document in an effort to be more precise.

---

There are only two other possibilities:

1. $f$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $\infty$.

   Recall that a neighbourhood of $\infty$ (inside $\mathbb{C}$) is a open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| > R\}$ for some $R \geq 0$. So if $f$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $\infty$, there is some $R \geq 0$ and $L \geq 0$ such that $|f(z)| \leq M$ for all $|z| > R$. As $f$ is continuous and $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| \leq R\}$ is compact, there is $K \geq 0$ such that $|f(z)| \leq K$ for all $|z| \leq R$. But then $|f(z)| \leq M := \max\{K, L\}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$; i.e. $f$ is bounded. By Liouville's Theorem, $f$ is constant which contradicts the fact that $f$ is injective.
2. $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

   By Picard's Great Theorem, $f$ takes on all but possibly one value infinitely many times in a neighbourhood of $\infty$ which contradicts the injectivity of $f$.

Therefore, $f$ must have a pole at $\infty$.